# ASP.Net OnClick Subs not operating how I want

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am using onClick handlers to process button clicks that query SQL. The problem is, sometimes these queries take 10 - 30 seconds before they return. I disabled the buttons to prevent click-stacking during that time, but now I would like to have a little loading gif appear while the sub finishes doing its thing.

So it would go like this: click -> button disabled -> loading gif appears -> onClick sub completes -> loading gif disappears -> more Ajax happens on same page

Here is what my button looks like

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonOne" runat="server" Visible="False" Text="Next" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="userName_Click"/>
```

And by page-behind

```
Sub userName_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    showWidget(True)
    'This part takes a few seconds
    If usernameIsValid(textField.Text)
    Then buttonTwo.Visible = true, labelTwo.Visible = true,   buttonOne.Visible = false, labelOne.Visible = false
     End If
    showWidget(False)
     End Sub
```

The result I am currently getting is that the .gif doesn't load (It only registers showWidget(Flase)).

How can I tie the loading image to the button click, then make the loading image go away after the subroutine of the click action finishes?

Thanks!

Comment: A server-side method cannot display or hide an image on the browser until the server sends a response, which is why you are seeing this behavior - it is expected. You can either look into submitting an ajax request, or possibly using an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Well, all my buttons are within an update panel. But maybe it isn't working because I used UseSubmitBehavior="false" ?

Comment: No that is not the problem. Try using an `UpdateProgress` control to hide/show the image. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This approach will not work. You need to use html button and on that botton click call your server-side method using AJAX, wnd show your animation/gif using jQuery/Bootstrap.